# Will this binary search algorithm run into infinite loop?

Tags: algorithm

The specific binary search implementation is shown as below. The question I want to ask is that is it possible for the algorithm to run into infinite loop?

One possible situation I could think of is when l == r == UINT_MAX and the target x is larger than all elements in the array. Is it true that under this situation, the algorithm will stuck in infinite loop?

Are there any other situations of running into infinite loop?

Thanks for your help!!!

```
// A iterative binary search function. It returns location of x in
// given array arr[l..r] if present, otherwise -1.
int binarySearch(vector<double> arr, double x) {
    unsigned int l = 0;
    unsigned int r = arr.size() - 1;
    while (l <= r) {
      int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
      if (arr[m] == x) 
          return m;  
      if (arr[m] < x) 
          l = m + 1; 
      else
          r = m - 1; 
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

Comment: If the input array is empty it will not necessarily loop indefinitely, but the program will most likely crash.

Comment: @jdehesa No, actually in that case it would never enter the while loop since r < l

Comment: @lebesgue Did I answer your question?

Comment: @A.Mashreghi My situation is l == r == UINT_MAX. So, it will enter the loop.

Comment: @A.Mashreghi it would entered the loop because `r` would be initialized to ` UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't! An infinite loop only happens here if l and r could possibly stay on the same value forever. For that to happen, one of these things need to happen:

1) new value of l = old value of l:

`m + 1 = l + (r - l) / 2 + 1 = l --> (r - l)/2 + 1 = 0` (which never happens since the left side is always positive knowing that r is already bigger equal than l)

2) new value of r = old value of r:

`m - 1 = l + (r - l) / 2 - 1 = r --> (r - l)/2 = r - l + 1` (this also never happens because the right side is always strictly bigger)

Comment: As the OP stated, if `l == r == UINT_MAX` and `x` is bigger than every element in the array you would loop forever because `l = m + 1` would set `l` to `0` again.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but doesn't it mean that for that happen, your array has to be as big as your whole memory? You are right, it could happen, but it is very extreme case in my humble opinion.